Expo Auth Session + Microsoft Entra ID - Can't properly sign out of mobile app
Been trying to add authentication via Microsoft Entra ID to an Expo-based mobile app, and while the sign in process works properly, I haven't been able to get the sign out part to work, as the post logout redirect just does not happen at all.
I followed the basic steps and set the scheme property in app.json to "myapp", then I registered "myapp://redirect" as a redirect URL to a Native/Desktop app in Microsoft Entra ID.
As suggested by the Expo Docs, I'm using Expo Auth Session alongside Expo Web Browser. (Link to the docs)
This is the discovery setup:
  const autoDiscovery = AuthSession.useAutoDiscovery(
    `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_TENANT_ID}/v2.0`
  );

  const redirectUri = AuthSession.makeRedirectUri({
    path: 'redirect',
  });

  const [request, , promptAsync] = AuthSession.useAuthRequest(
    {
      clientId: String(process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_CLIENT_ID),
      scopes: ['openid', 'profile', 'email', 'offline_access', 'User.Read'],
      redirectUri,
    },
    autoDiscovery
  );

And this is the signOut method:
  async function signOut() {
    const result = await WebBrowser.openAuthSessionAsync(
      `${
        autoDiscovery?.endSessionEndpoint
      }?post_logout_redirect_uri=${encodeURIComponent(redirectUri)}`,
      redirectUri
    );

    // if (result.type === 'success') {
    await clearAuthState();
    setAuth(null);
    // }
  }

Sign in works fine as I said, and I can complete the sign out in the popup window with Microsoft's logout interface, but the user does not get redirected back to the app and the only way out of the popup is by closing it, leading to a 'dismiss' result, the same result I get when I close the window before signing out, so it's important that I get the 'success' result. As you can see I had to temporarily comment out the result check, which causes the auth state to be cleared even if the user does not select an account to sign out of.
I have tried things such as listening for attempted redirects with Expo Linking so I would clear the persisted auth state manually when the listener picks up a specific redirect. I also tried several little tweaks, like adding a trailing slash to the post_logout_redirect_uri parameter, and nothing seems to work.
Also, I checked some old posts of similar or even the exact issue and wasn't able to make it work with the content I got from those old posts, so I wonder if anyone has run into this specific problem problem recently and happens to know a way to fix this.
Here is my package.json as well
  "dependencies": {
    "@date-fns/utc": "^1.2.0",
    "@expo/react-native-action-sheet": "^4.1.0",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^14.0.3",
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^3.9.0",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "11.3.1",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.7.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.2",
    "@shopify/react-native-skia": "1.2.3",
    "@tanstack/query-async-storage-persister": "^5.53.1",
    "@tanstack/react-query": "^5.51.11",
    "@tanstack/react-query-persist-client": "^5.53.1",
    "axios": "^1.7.3",
    "class-variance-authority": "^0.7.0",
    "date-fns": "^3.6.0",
    "eventemitter3": "^5.0.1",
    "expo": "^51.0.34",
    "expo-auth-session": "~5.5.2",
    "expo-background-fetch": "~12.0.1",
    "expo-blur": "~13.0.2",
    "expo-constants": "~16.0.2",
    "expo-crypto": "~13.0.2",
    "expo-dev-client": "~4.0.27",
    "expo-font": "~12.0.10",
    "expo-image": "~1.13.0",
    "expo-linking": "~6.3.1",
    "expo-router": "~3.5.23",
    "expo-secure-store": "~13.0.2",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.27.6",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.12.1",
    "expo-system-ui": "~3.0.7",
    "expo-task-manager": "~11.8.2",
    "expo-web-browser": "~13.0.3",
    "nativewind": "^2.0.11",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.52.2",
    "react-native": "0.74.5",
    "react-native-currency-input": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.16.2",
    "react-native-get-random-values": "~1.11.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-masked-text": "^1.13.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.10.1",
    "react-native-reanimated-carousel": "4.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.10.5",
    "react-native-screens": "3.31.1",
    "react-native-svg": "15.2.0",
    "react-native-ui-datepicker": "^2.0.3",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.10",
    "realm": "^12.13.1",
    "tailwind-merge": "^2.4.0",
    "uuid": "^10.0.0",
    "zod": "^3.23.8",
    "zustand": "^4.5.4"
  }


Yes me too getting this
